# Authentication mechanisms on Windows SSH server

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, sftp, authentication

I understand `SFTP` can use several means for authentication, including `passwords`, `public key pair`, `hashes` and `certificate` based authentication.

Some of these authentication mechanisms depend on the server's implementation of `SSH`. With `Windows 10` having an implementation of `OpenSSH` from version 1703 onward, I am not sure which authentication mechanisms are supported by the server.

I know it supports password and key based mechanisms, which I have tried out successfully, but I haven't found any literature or guide on the others, say `PKI certificates` etc. I'd like to avoid the use of passwords of course, and keys too, if possible, but not sure if Windows 10 based SSH supports it yet, or i it does, then how it is to be configured...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "PKI certificates"? OpenSSH has a proprietary ["public-key certificate authentication system"](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.certkeys?rev=1.16&content-type=text/plain) - Is it what you mean? (btw, I do not think there's any "hash" authentication).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The page here - https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/ - lists PKI based authentication, which uses a key. Presumably this will then preclude the need for key exchange per session later and replace that with certificate? I might be wrong...However, even assuming this is the way it works with OpenSSH, I'm not sure if Windows OpenSSH implementation supports this, based on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration. If it does (maybe this is a subset of key based authentication), then what would be the best way to go about it...

Comment: I believe that Win32-OpenSSH does support certificate-based authentication, while I never tested it. This is a relatively new feature and is not widely used and the documentation is sparse. If you further narrow down the question to Windows OpenSSH, I'm afraid you will have hard times to find anyone to answer. Consider asking a general question on OpenSSH certificate-based authentication. And once you have some idea how it works, it will probably be easy to configure it even in Windows. And if not, you will have a way more specific question(s) to ask.

Comment: You can start here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-creating_ssh_ca_certificate_signing-keys – The tools in Windows OpenSSH are the same as on *nix.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thank you, appreciate the help. I'll check it out.